# Writing 'bits' to C++ file streams

Tags: java, c#, python, c++, bit-manipulation

How can I write 'one bit' into a file stream or file structure each time?

Is it possible to write to a queue and then flush it?

Is it possible with C# or Java?

This was needed when trying to implement an instance of Huffman coding. I can't write bits into files, so write them to a bitset and then (when compression was completed) write 8-bit piece of it each time (exclude last one).

Comment: Did you miss any language? Most languages do not allow writing less than a byte at a time. You can test individual bits and print the results though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Buffering the individual bits until you've accumulated a whole byte seems like a good idea:

```
byte b;
int s;

void WriteBit(bool x)
{
    b |= (x ? 1 : 0) << s;
    s++;

    if (s == 8)
    {
        WriteByte(b);
        b = 0;
        s = 0;
    }
}
```

You just have to deal with the case when the number of bits to be written is not a multiple of eight.

Comment: Looks good. The last case could be handle with a `bool flush` argument and `if (s == 8 || flush)` test also.

Comment: Just make sure s is initialized to 0.

Comment: Note also that no "first" or "last" bit within a byte is defined or implied in the C standard, just most or least significant, maybe "left" and "right" as it relates to shifts. So WriteBit will have to decide for itself (and document) whether the bits should be written most or least significant first. You've gone for least significant, which is fair enough and Wikipedia claims it's by far the most common at the hardware level for serial comms. I've never made it deep enough into a serial driver to know for myself.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) along with [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) to achieve the desired result in a concise manner:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> Bitset;

// To help populate the bitset with literals */
Bitset& operator<<(Bitset& lhs, bool val) {lhs.push_back(val); return lhs;}

int main()
{
    Bitset bitset;
    bitset<<0<<1<<0<<1<<0<<1<<0<<1
          <<1<<0<<1<<0;

    std::ofstream os("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    std::ostream_iterator<char> osit(os);
    boost::to_block_range(bitset, osit);

    return 0;
}
```

I made the block size of my `dynamic_bitset` 8 bits by specifying `unsigned char` as the template parameter. You can make the block size bigger by specifying a larger integer type.

`boost::to_block_range` dumps the bitset in blocks to the given output iterator. If there are empty remainder bits in the last block, they'll be padded with zero.

When I open data.dat in a hex editor I see: `AA 05`. This is on a little endian platform (x64).

Answer (score 3):

Which filesystem are you using?

Most likely it stores the length of the file in bytes (are there *any* that don't?), so it's impossible to have a physical file that is not a whole number of bytes.

So if you are writing to the file as a stream of bits, you either have to truncate the last few bits when you are finished, or write out the final byte with what ammounts to junk in the remaining bits.

Here's some **Python** code to get you started

```
class BitFile(file):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        super(BitFile, self).__init__(filename, mode)
        self.bitCount=0
        self.byte = 0

    def write(self, bit):
        self.bitCount+=1
        self.byte = self.byte*2+bit
        if self.bitCount%8==0:
            super(BitFile, self).write(chr(self.byte))
            self.byte=0

    def close(self):
        if self.bitCount%8!=0:
            super(BitFile, self).write(chr(self.byte))
        super(BitFile, self).close()     

with BitFile("bitfile.bin","w") as bf:
    bf.write(1)
    bf.write(1)
    bf.write(1)
    bf.write(0)
    bf.write(0)
    bf.write(0)
    bf.write(0)
    bf.write(0)
    bf.write(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really.  I'm pretty sure the problem is not with the language or the filesystem, but a hardware issue.  Processors are designed to work with bytes.  Probably the closest you can do is write your last byte over and over again, right padded with zeros, changing them as you go, one at a time.

so to write bits '11011', you could do the following (python example, but any language should have facilities to do this:

```
f.write(chr(0b10000000))
f.flush()
f.seek(-1)
f.write(chr(0b11000000))
f.flush()
f.seek(-1)
f.write(chr(0b11000000))
f.flush()
f.seek(-1)
f.write(chr(0b11010000))
f.flush()
f.seek(-1)
f.write(chr(0b11011000)) 
f.flush()
```

You weren't hoping to get some sort of performance gain from this were you?

Comment: FYI, the C and C++ languages have no facilities for declaring binary constants.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend allocating a rather large buffer (4096 bytes at least) and flush that off to disk whenever it fills up. Using a one-byte buffer usually causes bad performance.

Comment: if I want to compress a huge file, like a glyph pos data of otf arabic. its size is 48 MB, after copmressing is 29MB. so your method is not theoretical. and wastes memory.

Comment: You misunderstood my method. I am simply suggesting a buffer larger than a byte, to make flushing far less frequent, not a buffer to fit your entire data in.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once for huffman decoding and ended up writing the bits as chars and thus handling everything internally as a plain old C string.

That way you don't have to worry about the trailing byte and it's human readable as well. Also checking bits is is easier since its just a matter of addressing the char array (`binbuf[123] == '1'`) instead of having to fiddle with bits. Not the most optimized solution, but it solved my problem neatly.

The obvious drawback is that this representation uses more memory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that many platforms do not have direct bit access.  They group bits into a minimal package, often times the *byte* or *word*.  Also, the protocol for stream devices does not facilitate transmission of individual bits.

The common method to deal with individual bits is to pack them into the smallest portable and (addressable) accessible unit.  The unused bits are usually set to zero.  This can be accomplished with binary arithmetic operations (OR, AND, EXCLUSIVE-OR, NOT, etc.).

With modern processors, bit twiddling slows down the machine and the performance.  Memory is cheap and with large addressing spaces, justification for bit packing has become more difficult.  Generally, bit packing is reserved for hardware oriented operations (and also transmission protocols).  For example, if a processor's *word* capacity is 16 bits, the processor can probably handle 16 words faster than 16 bit manipulations in one word.

Also, keep in mind that writing to and from memory is often faster than I/O from streams.  Efficient systems buffer data in memory before transmitting the data.  You may want to consider this technique in your designs.  Reducing I/O operations will improve the performance of your program.